# Assert-Method with dot Operator

Tags: android, assert, dot-operator

This is a question from a textbook with no answer key so it have to ask it here.

The "simple" version is:

```
assertEquals (resourceString, textView.getText());
```

If I have to use the dot-Operator for the "whole" version, would it be this?

```
Assert.assertEquals (resourceString, textView.getText());
```

Hope you can understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer that you are looking for is equals function.

```
resourceString.equals(textView.getText());
```

Comment: No the question is: What is the the whole method call of the assert Method.